# automate the shell script using oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I have to run a same script on a incoming data coming from flume again and again so I thought to automate it. So how do I automate a pig script using Oozie in a definite time interval?

Comment: Is the data arriving on hdfs? how often.  are you only writing complete files?  have you seen https://github.com/YahooArchive/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Comment: yes data is arriving on hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

shamelessly copied from https://github.com/YahooArchive/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Triggering Coordinator Jobs When Data File is Available
You can define input data dependencies for your Coordinator Job. Your Job will not run until the input file is created.

```
eg. hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/2010/06/01/03/trigger.dat
$ cat coordinator.xml
<coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="1440" start="2009-02-01T00:00Z" end="2009-02-07T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <datasets>
      <dataset name="input1" frequency="60" initial-instance="2009-01-01T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
         <uri-template>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}</uri-template>
         <done-flag>trigger.dat</done-flag>
      </dataset>
   </datasets>
   <input-events>
      <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
          <start-instance>${coord:current(-23)}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}</end-instance>
      </data-in>
   </input-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>     
</coordinator-app>
```

Comment: **<start-instance>${coord:current(-23)}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}**.  what is coord:current(-23) and coord:current(0) in this?

Comment: it is the period it is running over in this instance it is the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. You can create a Oozie workflow with necessary actions and write a shellscript to trigger the Oozie, and schedule it using cron job

Command to set cron job:

```
crontab -e
```

The advantage of writing a shell script is, you can set a failure e-mail notification, whenever some job fails.

2. Write a Oozie job with start and end time